# Wrapping of one huge raster with another raster and saving output such that both the rasters dimensions and crs match

Tags: raster, gdal, extents, pixel, dimensions

I have two huge rasters, I want my target raster dimensions , height width to match with my source raster and save my target raster into another folder. Since it is huge in size I want to do tile/kernel wise processing -

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import os

os.chdir(r'\\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap')

source_raster_path = r'\\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\source\Nig3.tif'
target_raster_path = r'\\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\target\Attri_comb1.tif'

tile_size_x = 512  # Define your tile size here
tile_size_y = 512  # Define your tile size here

ds = gdal.Open(source_raster_path)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)

xsize = band.XSize
ysize = band.YSize

for i in range(0, xsize, tile_size_x):
    for j in range(0, ysize, tile_size_y):
        tile_ds = gdal.Translate(target_raster_path + '_%d_%d.tif' % (i, j), ds, srcWin=[i, j, tile_size_x, tile_size_y], outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, creationOptions=['COMPRESS=LZW'])
        tile_ds = None

ds = None
```

But the output is not matching to what I expect. It is giving somewhat different raster with "0" values in it.

[image: Raster 1]

[image: Raster 2]

Comment: You could create a vector layer that is the same size as your source raster and just clip the second raster to that layer.

Comment: @Walshe_d how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gdal polygonize` to convert the first raster to vector and then use `gdal warp` or `gdal translate` to clip the second raster to the vector extent. [See the gdal manual here for more info](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html)

Comment: If this answered your question please mark as answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score -2):

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Tue Oct 10 23:44:14 2023

@author: schakraborty
"""

import os
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr

def create_vector_layer(extent, output_vector_path):
# Create a new shapefile for the vector layer
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
vector_ds = driver.CreateDataSource(output_vector_path)
spatial_ref = osr.SpatialReference()
spatial_ref.ImportFromEPSG(4326)  # Adjust the EPSG code as needed

```
# Create a new layer with the same spatial reference as the source raster
layer = vector_ds.CreateLayer("clip_extent", spatial_ref, ogr.wkbPolygon)

# Create a polygon feature representing the extent
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(extent[0], extent[1])
ring.AddPoint(extent[2], extent[1])
ring.AddPoint(extent[2], extent[3])
ring.AddPoint(extent[0], extent[3])
ring.AddPoint(extent[0], extent[1])

polygon = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
polygon.AddGeometry(ring)

feature_defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
feature = ogr.Feature(feature_defn)
feature.SetGeometry(polygon)

# Add the feature to the layer
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

# Clean up and close the vector dataset
vector_ds = None

return output_vector_path
```

def clip_raster_with_vector(input_raster, output_raster, vector_layer):
# Open the input raster and vector
input_ds = gdal.Open(input_raster)
vector_ds = ogr.Open(vector_layer)

```
if input_ds is None:
    print("Failed to open the input raster.")
    return

if vector_ds is None:
    print("Failed to open the vector layer.")
    input_ds = None  # Close the input raster
    return

# Clip the input raster using the vector layer
gdal.Warp(output_raster, input_ds, format="GTiff", cutlineDSName=vector_layer, cropToCutline=True)

# Clean up and close datasets
input_ds = None
vector_ds = None
```

if **name** == "**main**":
source_raster_path = r'\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\source\Nig3.tif'
target_raster_path = r'\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\target\Attri_comb1.tif'
output_vector_path = r'\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\shape_extent.shp'
clipped_raster_path = r'\CA1MDRMSEN06\Vinay\00_Projects\Global_LU\Nigeria\Rasters\Attribution\wrap\shape_extent.tif'

```
# Get extent from the source raster
source_ds = gdal.Open(source_raster_path)
if source_ds is not None:
    extent = source_ds.GetGeoTransform()
    extent = (extent[0], extent[3], extent[0] + extent[1] * source_ds.RasterXSize, extent[3] + extent[5] * source_ds.RasterYSize)
else:
    print("Failed to get extent from the source raster.")

# Create a vector layer with the same extent as the source raster
create_vector_layer(extent, output_vector_path)

# Clip the target raster using the vector layer
clip_raster_with_vector(target_raster_path, clipped_raster_path, output_vector_path)
```

Comment: This is a code dump not an answer